# Would it be possible to have comments that are flagged as offensive, immediately not viewable until they are moderated?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, flagging

Example:

[image]

I'm relatively secure in my sexuality, and laughed more than anything.  But, maybe it would be a good idea to have anyone with a reputation of over 1K be able to flag offensive content (making it temporarily invisible) until a moderator views it.  Maybe even give a limited number of flags based on rep (as rep goes up, number of flags go up) until you get to vote to close where this is no longer needed.

Comment: Is this a real issue?  It's enough to be considered under the legal definition of sexual harassment.  Do I really honestly care for my sake?  No.  For someone else... I don't know.  How fun is it to deal with legal issues?  If it's not a big deal, it's not a big deal.

Comment: not sure how it's a legal issue? Such cases are very, very rare and 6 offensive flags will wipe out the comment anyway.

Comment: Good enough then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, such cases are exceedingly rare and I'm not really certain this'll be as useful.

As the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) mentions, if a comment gets spam/offensive flagged enough number of times, it will be automatically deleted. And if the comment is offensive, more often than not it gets handled by the community before the Moderators can look at it.

Comment: According to the recent testing of comment flagging and autodeletion, it turns out that a single "rude or offensive" flag against a comment that contains a *known* bad word will result in the comment being autodeleted, similar to how a single "obsolete" flag against a comment containing the text "acceptance rate" (replace "acceptance" with "accept") will cause the comment to be autodeleted.